# G is a group and $(ab)^3=a^3b^3$ for all $a,b \in G$. Prove (or disprove with a counterexample) that if $(ab)^3=(ba)^3$, then $ab=ba$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> **Proposition.** Let $G$ be a group such that $(ab)^3=a^3b^3$ for all $a,b \in G$. If $(ab)^3=(ba)^3$, then $ab=ba$.

Is it true or false? So far I've only been able to prove that powers of $a$ commute with $b^3$ and powers of $b$ with $a^3$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $U(3, \mathbb F_3)$ be the group of all $3 \times 3$ upper triangular matrices with all diagonal entries $1$, over the field $\mathbb F_3$. Thus, the elements are all the matrices of the form $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & a & b\\0 & 1 & c\\0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$ where $a, b, c \in \mathbb F_3 = \{0,1,2\}$, the field of order $3$.

1. What is the exponent of the group [the least positive $n$ such that $g^n = 1$ for all group elements $g$]? Or: Determine the order of each element.
2. Is the group Abelian?
3. What do Points 1 and 2 imply about the status of the Proposition in this group?

Comment: Thank you. I guess I could have just as well asked if there exist non-abelian groups with maximum order 3. But what if I further impose that $(ab)^3=(ba)^3 \not = e$, where $e$ is the identity of $G$? Does it follow in that case?

Comment: @TheFootprint That's an odd imposition (doesn't really make sense as written), but let's say that you insist that the group should not have exponent $3$, so there should be at least one element $g$ such that $g^3 /ne 1$. Fine, let $H = U(3, \mathbb F_3)$ be the group described above, and let $K$ be your favourite Abelian group with exponent not equal to $3$ (say it $|K|$ is even, e.g.). Let $G = H \times K$ (direct product). Now $[(h_1, k_1)(h_2, k_2)]^3 = [(h_2, k_2)(h_1, k_1)]^3$ (Because the components get cubed and multiplied independently, and in each respective group the cubes commute!)

Comment: So this ↑ $G$ also satisfies the condition of the Proposition, but it's still not Abelian (Because the direct factor $H$ is not). However its exponent is not $3$.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, and the answer! May I ask how you came up with the example $U(3, \mathbb{F}_3)$? Is it a standard example? May I also ask what part of group theory one needs to prove the claim you've made, i.e. that $|K|$ even implies that its exponent cannot be $3$?

Comment: @TheFootprint I guess it's a somewhat standard example. Personally I know it from studying [power graphs of groups](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X10000531), where it is an important counterexample (for almost the same reason). The exponent of $G$ being the least positive integer $n$ (if any) such that $g^n = 1\ \forall g \in G$, it must be divisible by the order of every element of the group. Any finite group of even order has an element of order $2$ [this is a good basic exercise!], so its exponent cannot be $3$.

Comment: @TheFootprint Just to be clear: The exponent is not always the "maximum" order. For example, the maximum order of an element of $S_3$ is $3$, but the exponent of $S_3$ is $6$ (because there are some elements of order $2$). In other words, the exponent need not be the order of any element of the group. However, that is in a non-Abelian group. In an Abelian group of finite exponent, there is always an element of order equal to the exponent!

Comment: Thanks! Is your last claim a basic exercise as well?

Comment: @TheFootprint Yes, that makes for a more involved exercise. You may first need to make a couple of observations about how element orders work in Abelian groups, then prove this. The proof of this itself needs some thinking, maybe some small construction — so in short, it's the kind of proof that is very common in group theory (especially finite group theory).